# datosMySql Loading class This is deprecated. The new driver class is

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Estoy aprendiendo programación y me encuentro luchando con un problema en mi aplicación web. He hecho la misma aplicacion usando SQLServer y no he tenido problemas pero al cambiar la cadena de conexión para hacerlo funcionar con MySQL deja de funcionar.

Estoy intentando validar un login usando una consulta de usuario y contraseña en la base de datos a través de una sentencia `select`. La base de datos creada en Mysql es idéntica a la que hice en SQLServer (de hecho he probado el query y no hay problemas).

El único error que me lanzó fue con el conector que me mandó este mensaje:

> `Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'`

y que se solucionó añadiendo esa "cj". El resto es completamente igual.

Dejo mis clases implementadas y agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme. Por cierto, uso el Netbeans IDE 8.2, MySQL 8.0 y este conector "mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar"

clase conexion:

```
package conexion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {

private static Conexion instancia=null;
private static Connection con=null;
private static final String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mantenimiento?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";
private static final String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String usuario="sa";
private static final String clave="123456";

public Conexion() {
    
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, clave);
        System.out.println("Conectado");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }    
}

public synchronized static Conexion conectar(){
if(instancia==null){
  instancia = new Conexion();        
}
return instancia;
}

public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}

public void cerraConexion(){    
    instancia=null;
}
```

clase Usuario:

```
package dtos;


public class Usuario {
private String correo;
private String clave;

public Usuario(String correo, String clave) {
    this.correo = correo;
    this.clave = clave;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

}
```

Clase LoginDAO:

```
package daos;

import conexion.Conexion;
import dtos.Usuario;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class LoginDAO {
private static final String sql_select="select * from usuario where correo=? and clave=?";
private static PreparedStatement pstm=null;
private static ResultSet res = null;
private static Conexion con = Conexion.conectar();

public boolean validarLogin(Usuario usuario){
    boolean resultado=false;
    try {
        
        pstm = con.getCon().prepareStatement(sql_select);
        pstm.setString(1,usuario.getCorreo());
        pstm.setString(2,usuario.getClave());
        res =pstm.executeQuery();
        
        if(res.next()){
         resultado=true;
        }      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if(res!=null)res.close();
            if(pstm!=null)pstm.close();
            if(con!=null)con.cerraConexion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
   return resultado; 
    
}

}
```

Servlet controlador:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String correo = request.getParameter("txtCorreo");
    String clave = request.getParameter("txtClave");
    
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario(correo, clave);
    LoginDAO login  = new LoginDAO();
    
    if (login.validarLogin(usuario)) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("correo",usuario.getCorreo());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("sistema.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    } else {
       String error = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto"; 
       request.getSession().setAttribute("error",error);
       request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response); 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar qué quieres decir exactamente con "no funciona"?¿Y estás comprobando los logs para asegurarte que no te aparecen mensajes de los `System.out.println` que tienes en los `catch`?

Comment: Estas seguro que le dejaste el mismo usuario y clave que en el sql server?

Comment: Deberias revizar el usuario y contraseña de la BD por defecto en mysql es:
Root y "" respectivamente.

Comment: Tengo una pagina de bienvenida cuando lo datos del login son correctos y una de error cuando son incorrectos pero a pesar de que los datos son correctos siempre me envia a la página de error. En el primer “try” de la clase “conexión“  agregué un “system.out.println(“conectado”) para saber si estaba haciendo la conexión y la verdad es que se conecta pero no valida los datos en la base de datos a pesar de que todo es similar (tipos de datos, datos, nombres de los campos)

Comment: El usuario y password los modifique al instalar la instancia de Mysql y la probe creando una conexión en “servicios” de netbeans y lo hace sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de solucionarlo desinstalando la versión 8.0 de MySQL e instalando la version 5.7
Honestamente no entiendo cual pudo haber sido el error y no creo que sea la solución más correcta pero al menos funciona.

Comment: el fallo es por que mysql 8 a diferencia de mysql 5.7 usa un algortimo de cifrado de contraseñas de usuario distinto a sus predecesores y si el driver que usas para conectarte no esta actualizado, dará fallo

Comment: Buen dato! me pregunto cómo haré el día que, obligatoriamente, tenga que actualizar a MySQL 8  . Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Puede ser el el JDBC de java que es la libreria de mysql para la conexion, no se cual uses yo uso la 5.1.47 y uso MySql 13 con workbench 8 y xampp ultima version y funciona de maravilla tal vez puedas probar eso para no desactualizarte en programas si es lo que deseas

Comment: @MarcoGaribaldi te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Hace aproximadamente 3 años que la clase controlador para mysql `(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)` dejo de proporcionar Servicio( quedó obsoleta y deprecado) para la versión de Mysql Connector 8.0 en adelante, por eso es que cambiando a `'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'` no hay problema para ninguna versión de Mysql.
Si se quiere seguir usando el controlador antiguo se debe cambiar a una version inferior de Mysql Connector 8.0 para que funcione, como hizo Marco Garibaldi.

### **Solución con Maven**

Si estás utilizando Maven, y querés seguir usando `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` cambia la versión de Mysql Connector a una más antigua(de 6.0.6 hacia abajo) en su dependencia dentro del pom.xml...

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

### **Solución sin Maven (con el .jar)**

Si no estás usando Maven, querés seguir usando `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` y tenés un .jar descargado, asegurate de que tengas una versión posterior a la 8.0.
No sabés donde conseguir el .jar? clickea el link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.47 y descargalo de ahí